# Trying to create delete button to delete records in database

Tags: php, html, sql, database, mysqli

I am making a school project.

The meaning of this project is that i create a `login/registration form`,

where i can register, login, view the record.

But i also need to make a dropdown menu were i can see all the records (users) and below it i need to make a button and when i select a record/user and press the delete button it need to be deleted from the database. and i have no clue how i can do this.

**here is my code:**

```
<?php
```

include ("connectie.php");
include ("deletecode.php");

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "student14_admin", "lol12345","student14_jordi");
mysqli_select_db($conn,'student14_jordi');

$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE ID='$_GET[id]'";



echo "<select name='user'>";
    if ($result->num_rows>0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value=" . $row['username'] . ">" . $row['username'] . "</option>";
    }
    }
    echo "</select>";

?>


<form action="">
<a class="delete" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a button and name it Delete

```
<a class="delete" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Delete</a>
```

Then make a delete.php file and have these code there.

```
<?php include_once 'db_config_filename.php';
 // get id value
 $id = $_GET['id'];

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE id='$id'";

// print_r($sql);

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
   echo "Record deleted successfully";
} 
else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

 //redirect here
include 'data.php';

?>
```

Comment: i updated the code now i also got an extra file for the delete code

Comment: syntax problem

DELETE FROM users WHERE id =$_GET['id'];


still without seeing all the codes I couldn't get you

Comment: Sorry i don't understand that so what do i need to do? because nothing is working now

Answer (score 0):

I almost have it working. i have now this code:

```
delete.php:

<?php

include ("connectie.php");


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<select name='user'>";
    if ($result->num_rows>0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value=" . $row['username'] . ">" . $row['username'] . " 
</option>";
    }
    }
    echo "</select>";

?>


<form action="" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value=".$row['id']." />
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="verwijderen">
</form>

<?php
    include ("deletecode.php");
?>

Deletecode.php:

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "student14_admin";
$password = "lol12345";
$dbname = "student14_jordi";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=3";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

well this works for only record 3 afcourse. but now i need to have it that if i select a record from the dropdown menu and click on the delete button it needs to delete that record from my database.